# Почему появляется ошибка

Tags: php

Мне необходимо с помощью php выдавать дату завтрашнего дня в формате yyyy-mm-dd
я погуглил и нашел вот это выражение `<?php $tomorrow  = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")+1, date("Y")); ?>`  оно конечно не того формата, но оно не работает, выдается ошибка

> syntax error unexpected t_string, expecting `,` or `)`

Скриншот кода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не воспроизводится, в приведенном фрагменте кода ошибки никакой нет

Comment: @teran вот посмотрите https://cloud.mail.ru/public/9z32/ubFynAzSm

Comment: @Arcadiy там совсем не поэтому ошибка. кавычки правильно расставьте. и в таким вопросах код нужно публиковать в самом вопросе, а не изображением

Comment: @Alex Вы правы. Оформите пожалуйста ответом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка не в этом, судя по скриншоту ошибка в неправильно расставленных кавычках.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

В фрагменте кода который Вы привели ошибок нет.

Вот еще один вариант реализации:

```
$date  = new DateTime();
$date  ->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
$tomorrow= $date->format('Y-m-d') ;
echo $tomorrow;
```

Comment: А как мне вставить этот код в эту строку заместо звездочек curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "api.travelpayouts.com/v1/prices/direct?currency=RUB&origin=MOW&destination=AER&depart_date=********");

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "api.travelpayouts.com/v1/prices/direct?currency=RUB&origin=‌​MOW&destination=AER&‌​depart_date=".$tomorrow); Это вместо echo $tomorrow;